# convert string (JS object format) to PHP object

Tags: php, json

How I can convert string from URL to PHP object ? I know that its not valid JSON format but I still don't know how to convert it properly.

The following code returns NULL:

```
 $url = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js';
 $decodedCurrencies = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
 var_dump($decodedCurrencies);
```

Comment: you must pull page content first

Comment: Its not JSON  its returning the js script

Comment: Yes, I know but how I can convert this String from URL to PHP object ?

Comment: @Zeljka You mean the file_get_contents at line 2?

Comment: @Andreas yeah..

Comment: @Zeljka So what is your first comment about then? OP does "pull" the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use regex to extract rates array and then decode it.

Something like this:

```
$url = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/javascripts/currencies.js';
$script = file_get_contents($url);
$matches = [];
preg_match('/.+(\{.+}).+/', $script, $matches);

$decodedCurrencies = json_decode($matches[1]);
var_dump($decodedCurrencies);
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (179) {
  ["USD"]=>
  float(1)
  ["EUR"]=>
  float(1.1637)
  ["GBP"]=>
  float(1.31291)
  ["CAD"]=>
  float(0.778138)
  ["ARS"]=>
  float(0.0566433)
  ["AUD"]=>
  float(0.766026)
  ["BRL"]=>
  float(0.303944)
  ["CLP"]=>
  float(0.00157516)
...
}
```

Comment: @PawełKwiatkowski, what's the problem? Let's check and fix together

Comment: there is no output at all, var_dump($decodedCurrencies); returns empty page

Comment: @PawełKwiatkowski, it seems strange, I've tested it on php5 and php7.

Comment: @PawełKwiatkowski, could you please provide output from next code? `var_dump(file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: I've found what was wrong, I've changed:
$matches = []; to $matches = array();
and it is working now :), thank you ! :)